# A basic question on limit point neighbouhood interior point etc

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Can a limit point $p$ of a set $E$ $(p \notin E)$ be an interior point of $closure(E)$ ? Now, if $p$ has a neighbourhood contaning only $p$ then in that case it becomes an interior point of $E$.

But, I am not able to think of any example currently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: let $E=\Bbb Q$ as a subset of $\Bbb R$ with its usual topology. Then $\operatorname{cl}E=\Bbb R$, which is open in $\Bbb R$, so every point of $\operatorname{cl}E$, whether it was in $E$ or not, is in the interior of $\operatorname{cl}E$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be the rationals in $[1,2]$. Then $\sqrt{2}$ is an interior point of the closure of $E$.